# Render not scaling to the appropriate resolution (not filling entire canvas)

Tags: rendering, export

My render is not filling the entire canvas. I had the render resolution at 1000x1000 for a while, before I changed it to 3000x3000 as I was going to do a final render.

How can I make it fill the entire canvas? When exporting, the blank space is still there.

Attached is an image of the issue, and my render settings.

[image]

[image: What is all of this blank space?]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: have you accidentally enabled a [render border](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/navigate/clip.html#render-border)?  If so, type CTRL-ALT-B in the 3D Viewport to remove it.  Meanwhile, your render above hasn't finished.  It shows 0 of 4 tiles rendered.  The render engine only renders part of the scene at once if the tile size is smaller than the image size.  Is that the issue?

Comment: @MartyFouts oh I didn't know that about tile sizes. That was the issue... rookie mistake. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome. I like your composition so far, by the way.